# How to Link Excel to Word?

Tags: excel

So basically in Excel, i have rows and rows of data. I have created this search facility which allows users to search for a product code. I am now trying to have a button in the column which then transfers this over to a word document.

[image: Example Work Sheet]

So the word document will be a product specification - and will have this information from the row inserted in different locations. And will need to be updated each time a user searches a different product code.

Any help please

Shane

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far (the code) and describe what went wrong?

Comment: Isn't that the whole purpose of [mail merge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3)?

Comment: What about pasting in word as a link?

Comment: Mail Merge would be best option for this case.

Comment: Thank you for your comments i have found a solution for this :)